# No sound from external speakers/headphones (jack)

Tags: sound, 13.10, headphones, speakers, jack

I've got constant problem, after instaling Ubuntu 13.10. I get no sound from the audio jack (speakers, headphones etc) but my internal speakers work right, playing sound as they should. Tried many "workarounds"a found here, but not even one seems to fix the problem ... My laptop is ASUS K55VM, if You need any command-output just ask, and I will post it ( due to being completely linux-noob, I don't want to post any nonesense).

Answer (score 1):

Type `alsamixer` into your terminal. Then scroll with your directional keys to the right until the tab "auto-mute" is highlighted red. If your problem is anything like mine, it will be "Enabled." Hit the up directional arrow to change the status to "Disabled." That did the trick for me.